# sed find pattern on line with another pattern

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to extract text from a file between a `<` and a `>`, but only on a line starting with another specific pattern.

So in a file that looks like:

```
XXX Something here  
XXX Something more here  
XXX <\Lines like this are a problem> 
ZZZ something <\This is the text I need> 
XXX Don't need any of this
```

I would like to print only the `<\This is the text I need>`.

If I do

```
sed -n '/^ZZZ/p' FILENAME
```

it pulls the correct lines I need to look at, but obviously prints the whole line.

```
sed -n '/<\/,/>/p' FILENAME prints way too much.
```

I have looked into grouping and tried

```
sed -n '/^ZZZ/{/<\/,/>/} FILENAME
```

but this doesn't seem to work at all.

Any suggestions? They will be much appreciated.

(Apologies for formatting, never posted on here before)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sed -n '/^ZZZ/ { s/^.*\(<.*>\).*$/\1/p }'
```

Comment: The braces are actually redundant here; the general syntax is _address_ _action_ and so you can simply say, on lines which match the addressing regex `/^ZZZ/` perform the `s` command; `/^ZZZ/s/.*\(<.*>\).*/\1/p`. The wildcards mean find the _last_ `<` followed by the _last_ `>` later on the line; maybe use `[^<>]*` instead of `.*` to not skip straddling `<`or `>` characters if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If it does not have to be sed and you have a fairly recent grep, you may use grep's option -o as in

```
grep '^ZZZ' | grep -o '<[^>]*>'
```

Comment: Went with the guy above because of sed, but still thank you. I'd give you a vote, but it appears I am too new.

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` version

```
awk -F"<|>" '/^ZZZ/ {print "<"$2">"}' file
<\This is the text I need>
```